# How do I change colours of different bars in SAS?

Tags: sas, sgplot

```
proc sgplot data=WORK.CUSTOMERDATA;
    title height=14pt "Bar Chart of Gender";
    vbar Gender / fillattrs= (color=CX024ae6) datalabel;
    
    yaxis grid;
run;

ods graphics / reset;
title;
```

[image: Bar Chart of Graduated]

how do I change the colour of individual bars ? I have tried fill= and styleattrs datacolors= but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you wish to have one color for the graduated and another for the ones that did not, the following should provide the desired output

```
proc sgplot data=customerdata;
title height=14pt "Bar Chart of Graduated";
styleattrs datacolors=(blue red) ;
vbar Graduated / group=Graduated filltype=solid datalabel;
yaxis grid;
run;
```

[image]